# Can anyone figure out why my loops are falling through?

Tags: c++, loops, validation, int, cin

this is my first post here. I am new to c++ (just started last week) and have spent a few hours on this and am stumped.

I am aware that I am probably doing many things wrong in this program, but I assure you all I have tried my best. Validating inputs is beyond the scope of my homework, but I wanted to try it out since just getting inputs and returning them is boring.

Basically, the input validation works for the outer loop, but with the inner loops it will fall through even if invalid.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Global Variables

int cubeLength = 0;
int cubeWidth = 0;
int cubeHeight = 0;
int cubeSurfaceArea = 0;
int cubeVolume = 0;
bool valid = false;

int main() {

//Ask user for cubeLength and validate input for integer values
do {
cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the length of a cube" <<endl;
cin >> cubeLength;
    if (cin.good()) {
        valid = true;
        //Ask user for cubeWidth and validate input for integer values
        do {    
            cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the width of a cube" <<endl;
            cin >> cubeWidth;
            if (cin.good()) {
                valid = true;
                //Ask user for cubeHeight and validate input for integer values
                do {
                    cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the height of a cube" <<endl;
                    cin >> cubeHeight;
                    if (cin.good()) {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        cin.clear();
                        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
                        cout << "Invalid cube height. Please try again" << endl;
                    }
                }while (!valid);
            }
            else
            {   
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
                cout << "Invalid cube width. Please try again" << endl;
            }
        }while (!valid);
    }
    else
    {   
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid cube length. Input is not an integer" << endl;
    }
} while (!valid);


//Perform calculations for surface area and volume then assign them to their associated variables
if (cubeLength >= 1 && cubeWidth >= 1 && cubeHeight >= 1)
    {
        valid = true;
        cubeSurfaceArea = ((2*(cubeWidth*cubeLength))+(2*(cubeLength*cubeHeight))+(2*(cubeWidth*cubeHeight)));
        cubeVolume = (cubeWidth*cubeLength*cubeHeight);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Sorry, one or more cube inputs is invalid. Ending program. Please restart and try again." << endl;
        return 0;
    }   

//Output surface area and volume to user
cout << "Length = " << cubeLength << " Width = " << cubeWidth << " Height = " << cubeHeight << endl;
cout << "The surface area of your cube is " << cubeSurfaceArea << "." << endl;
cout << "The volume of your cube is " << cubeVolume << "." << endl;

//Pause system and end program
return 0;
}
```

I added the if statement for the calculations at the bottom to stop this from falling all of the way through the program and exit.

I have also checked a lot of similar questions on validating inputs for integers and loops on this site and others, but haven't been able to figure it out. My theory is that i'm either messing up the boolean logic for valid, or using the wrong looping method.

Comment: Are you sure cin.good() is the right call for what you're trying to do? Docs suggest this will check the state of the cin stream for EOF or a read/write failure, which doesn't sound like it's going to validate the actual contents of the stream...

Comment: cin.good works for the first loop when evaluating, so as a newbie that was what i settled with. I can input decimals and strings and it will be invalid every time like it's supposed to be, but the fall through is in the boolean logic I think.

I also was having trouble finding good documentation around cin.good, do you have any suggestions I can look at/should be aware of?

Really appreciate it.

Comment: It's generally better to test the actual input operation, like `if(cin >> foo) ...`

Comment: @B00489663 There's a few references for this, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/ is one of them. Basically I'm not sure that the code as written is doing what you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with the loops is that you are setting `valid` to `true` but never to `false`, so the statement `while (!valid)` will never evaluate to false.

Another general comment is that the layout of the code has too many nested loops. This can be simplified a lot.

I did not test the code below, but this type of structure is much easier to read - ie doing each input separately, rather than jumbling the all together! :-)

```
//Ask user for cubeLength and validate input for integer values
valid = true;
do {
     cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the length of a cube" <<endl;
     cin >> cubeLength;
     if (!cin.good()) {
        valid = false;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid cube length. Input is not an integer" << endl;
    }     
} while (!valid);

//Ask user for cubeWidth and validate input for integer values
do {
    cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the width of a cube" <<endl;
    cin >> cubeWidth;
    if (!cin.good()) {
        valid = false;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid cube width. Please try again" << endl;
   }    
} while (!valid);


//Ask user for cubeHeight and validate input for integer values
do {
    cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the width of a cube" <<endl;
    cin >> cubeWidth;
    if (!cin.good()) {
        valid = false;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid cube height. Please try again" << endl;
    } 
 }while (!valid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my hunch was on the boolean logic, so I'll go back and mess with it and see if I can do it. I did try setting it to false in the else statement, but i still fell through last time i tried.

 I didn't originally have the loops nested, I have moved things around a ton. First they were just consecutive if statement, then i tried do while loops, then i tried separating them into functions of their own for each input.

Each configuration resulted in the same result. In general though, I would love any tips for improving the layout/structure of the code.

Comment: @B00489663  See how simpler this is to read. Even still a lot of code is repeated so there is an opportunity to make a function as next step - happy learning!

Comment: Definitely much easier, I think I fell into the trap of over complicating code when it isn't working. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @B00489663 ok no worries. you need to accept the answer or upvote so other can see its done.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't since this is my first post. Just made the account today for school, so I don't have enough points to upvote or select a best answer. You are awesome for helping me though.

Comment: @B00489663 May I ask you to look see, if there is a check mark (tick) under the up/down vote area of my reply. If so click on it to accept if you like. I think you don't need any reputation badges to accept the answer, (but I agree not allowed to upvote). This is more for curiosity on my part to see how it works, because I am fairly new to Stackflow myself.

Comment: There was, and I was able to mark it as the answer. This is why I should have read through the tutorial :)

Comment: @B00489663 Nobody reads tutorials unless forced! Lol. I just read it up myself because I had no idea how to accept either. For the record, accepting an answer or up/down voting is completely optional and people who answer questions are not supposed to ask for upvote or acceptance ( I just read also). But in my opinion is polite to accept answers if they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

After the first time you set `valid = true`, it stays `true` till the end. You should take it back to `false` before testing it again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who provided help and feedback:

The issue is painfully obvious to me now, which is the boolean value not being reset at the beginning of the loop after a failed validation on input.

I redid the entire code per suggestions and have a stable program now!:)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Global Variables

int cubeLength = 0;
int cubeWidth = 0;
int cubeHeight = 0;
int cubeSurfaceArea = 0;
int cubeVolume = 0;
bool valid = true;
char choice;

int main() {
do {
//Ask user for cubeLength and validate input for integer values
do {
valid = true;
cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the length of a cube" <<endl;
cin >> cubeLength;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        valid = false;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid cube length. Input is not an integer" << endl;
        }
    } while (!valid);

//Ask user for cubeWidth and validate input for integer values
do {    
    valid = true;
    cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the width of a cube" <<endl;
    cin >> cubeWidth;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        valid = false;  
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid cube width. Input is not an integer" << endl;
    }
} while (!valid);
//Ask user for cubeHeight and validate input for integer values
do {
    valid = true;
    cout << "Please enter a numerical value for the height of a cube" <<endl;
    cin >> cubeHeight;
    if (cin.fail()) {   
        valid = false;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid cube height. Input is not an integer" << endl;
    }
}while (!valid);

//Perform calculations for surface area and volume then assign them to their associated variables
if (cubeLength >= 1 && cubeWidth >= 1 && cubeHeight >= 1)
    {
        cubeSurfaceArea = ((2*(cubeWidth*cubeLength))+(2*(cubeLength*cubeHeight))+(2*(cubeWidth*cubeHeight)));
        cubeVolume = (cubeWidth*cubeLength*cubeHeight);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Sorry, one or more cube inputs is invalid. Ending program. Please restart and try again." << endl;
        return 0;
    }   

//Output surface area and volume to user
cout << "Length = " << cubeLength << " Width = " << cubeWidth << " Height = " << cubeHeight << endl;
cout << "The surface area of your cube is " << cubeSurfaceArea << "." << endl;
cout << "The volume of your cube is " << cubeVolume << "." << endl;
cout << "Would you like to try again? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> choice;

} while (choice != 'n');

//Pause system and end program
return 0;
}
```